# Dynamically loading a module that is not in a script tag with type="module"?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is it possible to use import without a script tag already in place for said module?

My problem is that I want to load modules dynamically based on a config file, for example :

Folder structure :

```
|-- main.js
|-- config.json.js
|-- modules
    |-- module1.js
    |-- module2.js
    |-- module3.js
```

Index.html head :

```
<script src="/config.json.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="/main.js"></script>
```

config.json.js :

```
export default {

  modules : ['module1', 'module3']

}
```

main.js :

```
import config from '/config.json.js'

//Loading modules defined in config
config.modules.forEach(moduleName => {
  import(`modules/${moduleName}`)
  .then( module => {
    console.log(`${module.name} loaded.`);
  )}
})
```

The above won't work as the modules haven't been defined in a script tag.

Is there any way I can achieve this using vanilla JS and keeping it clean?

Comment: Frameworks are written in vanilla JS, so if it's possible in a framework, it's possible in JS. That said, this seems a bit like an abuse of modules.

Comment: can you create a script tag dynamically and append it to the head?

Comment: You don't need `<script src="/config.json.js" type="module"></script>` at all, delete that. Instead the **importing** file must be included using `type="module"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, as long as your loader script is marked as `module`

```
<script type="module">
  const moduleSpecifier = './myModule.mjs';
  import(moduleSpecifier)
    .then((module) => {
      // do something
    });
</script>
```

Although, in your case, a simple `forEach` may not be enough. You may need `Promise.all` or similar if you want to wait for ***all*** the modules to load from your config.

```
const modules = config.modules.map(moduleName => import(`modules/${moduleName}`))

Promise.all(modules)
  .then(modules => {
    // modules is an array of all your loaded modules
    console.log('All modules loaded.');
  )}
```

Further reading:

- https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import

Comment: Thank you, beautiful answer, although it does seem kinda weird that module property goes to the loader and not the modules I'm glad it's like that.

Comment: I just realized this doesn't work if any of the dynamically loaded modules also have imports inside them, right?

Comment: There should be no need for `type="module"` as expressed in the first snippet -- also non-module scripts should be (today) able to utilize the `import` _function_.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit!** [Dynamic import has landed in Firefox 67+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports).

```
  (async () => {
    await import('./synth/BubbleSynth.js')
  })()
```

https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import

---

**Old answer:**

To import further modules **after DOM load**, one not so clean but working way can be to create a new caller script of type module.

```
/* Example */
/* Loading BubbleSynth.js from «synth» folder*/
let dynamicModules = document.createElement("script")
dynamicModules.type = "module"
dynamicModules.innerText = "import * as bsynth from '../synth/BubbleSynth.js'"
/* One module script already exist. eq: «main.js», append after it */ 
document.querySelector("script[type='module']").parentElement.appendChild(dynamicModules)
```

Destroying the module caller script does not harm the past calls:

```
document.querySelectorAll("script[type='module']")[1].outerHTML = ""
// *BubbleSynth* is still in memory and is running
```

But appending a new module call to that script does not works. A new caller module script must be created.

As a function:

```
function dynModule(me){
  let dyn = document.createElement("script")
  dyn.type = "module"
  dyn.innerText = `import * as ${me} from '../synth/${me}.js'`
  document.querySelector("script[type='module']").parentElement.appendChild(dyn)
  document.querySelectorAll("script[type='module']")[1].outerHTML = ""
}

dynModule("BubbleSynth")
```